# Converting Excel formula with self reference to SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, stored-procedures

I'm in the progress of converting a huge Excel file to a SQL Server stored procedure to achieve some automation. I just stumbled about an excel column which references itself. I have no idea how to convert this in to a stored procedure. Maybe you guys can help.

This is the part of the excel I imported into SQL Server:

```
+------------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+
| PLAYER LAST NAME |  DRILL TITLE   | SESSION DATE | TOTAL DISTANCE |
+------------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+
| Fernandes        | Entire Session | 05.08.2020   |           5565 |
| Fernandes        | Entire Session | 06.08.2020   |           3484 |
+------------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+
```

In Excel, there is a formula for a column called "Total Distance EWMA (28)" and it goes like:

```
=IFERROR((AVERAGEIFS([Total Distance EWMA (28)];[PLAYER LAST NAME];[@[PLAYER LAST NAME]];[DRILL TITLE];"Entire Session";[SESSION DATE];[@[SESSION DATE]]-1));[@[TOTAL DISTANCE]])
```

The desired output of the stored procedure would be:

```
+------------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+-----------------------------+
| PLAYER LAST NAME |  DRILL TITLE   | SESSION DATE | TOTAL DISTANCE | Total Distance EWMA (28) |
+------------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+-----------------------------+
| Fernandes        | Entire Session | 05.08.2020   |           5565 |                        5565 |
| Fernandes        | Entire Session | 06.08.2020   |           3484 |                        5565 |
+------------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+-----------------------------+
```

But my problem is calculating the average in the stored procedure. In my target table, the column of "Total Distance EWMA (28)" is empty.

So

```
SELECT AVG([Total Distance EWMA (28)]) FROM target;
```

would always return null when selecting the data to pass into my target table. I would need to calculate the average of this column in my target table for every row I insert.

Is there any clever way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a window function:

```
SELECT AVG([Total Distance]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Player Last Name]) as avg_distance
FROM target;
```

You can incorporate this into an `UPDATE` as well, but it is not clear if that is part of the question:

```
with toupdate as (
      SELECT t.*,
             AVG([Total Distance]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Player Last Name]) as avg_distance
      FROM target t
     )
update toupdate
    set avg_total_disance = avg_distance;
  FROM target;
```